# IOS can i integrate scenekit or spritekit with single view application

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, scenekit

I am trying to integrate any gaming kit (like scenekit or sprite kit) inside my utility based single view application , so is it possible to integrate any game kit with single view application what is the approach to start integrating game using objective c/swift.  i can develop simple games using UIKit framework, but i want to try more interesting things in my apps. so what is the best option to integrate gaming in single view applications.

Thanks for your advice

Comment: Why not simply use the "Game" template when creating a new project?

Comment: Thanks i didn't tried that :D

Comment: This is one of the claimed advantages of Scene Kit and SpriteKit. Unfortunately Apple only claims this, and doesn't provide any good little examples of how to do it that's performant. And there's lots of caveats. Do it the wrong ways (and there's many, apparently) and the performance falls off a cliff.

Answer (score 1):

To answer this, Yes you can.  All it takes is adding a view to your view controller, giving it the custom `SKView` class,  then inside of your view controller code, use the view that is attached with the `SKView` class to present the scene that you want to be working with.